# Apache Felix Filter Issue

Tags: java, servlet-filters, apache-felix, sling, osgi-bundle

I'm developing an Apache Sling WCMS application. I need to filter all requests sent to the server and set some headers in response object. I implemented filter and bundle activator class according to [Felix Http Filter Sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/trunk/http/samples/filter/) and installed as bundle to sling.

Fileter class:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {
    private final String name;

    public HeaderFilter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        doLog("Init with config [" + config + "]");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            doLog("Filter request [" + request + "]");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
            chain.doFilter(req, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        doLog("Destroyed filter");
    }

    private void doLog(String message) {
        System.out.println("## [" + this.name + "] " + message);
    }
}
```

Bundle Activator class:

```
import org.apache.felix.http.api.ExtHttpService;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;

import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    private ServiceTracker tracker;
    private HeaderFilter filter1 = new HeaderFilter("filter1");
    Dictionary hashTable = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        try {
            this.tracker = new ServiceTracker(context, ExtHttpService.class.getName(), null) {
                @Override
                public Object addingService(ServiceReference ref) {
                    Object service = super.addingService(ref);
                    serviceAdded((ExtHttpService) service);
                    return service;
                }

                @Override
                public void removedService(ServiceReference ref, Object service) {
                    serviceRemoved((ExtHttpService) service);
                    super.removedService(ref, service);
                }
            };

            this.tracker.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context)
            throws Exception {
        this.tracker.close();
    }

    private void serviceAdded(ExtHttpService service) {
        try {
            hashTable.put("filter.scope", new String[]{"request", "forward", "include"});
            service.registerFilter(this.filter1, ".*", hashTable, 0, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void serviceRemoved(ExtHttpService service) {
        service.unregisterFilter(this.filter1);
    }
}
```

The is a problem with the code above. It's not working and no request will be filtered.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can implement this in a much simpler way using Sling Filters implemented as OSGi Declarative Services (DS).

You'll then just need a few annotations in your Filter, no Activator and the correct pom.xml setup for the Maven plugins that handle the DS annotations.

The documentation is at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html and it points to the [NoPropertyFilter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/filters/NoPropertyFilter.java) example from the Sling integration tests.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please say what's wrong with using activator? Using annotations, instead of activator class, has special advantages? Is there any special standard to declare such services?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an Activator, but it's a lot more code, most of it boilerplate. Declarative Services will also handle dependencies between services automatically, which in your case you have to do manually. There's no special standard for declaring such services, the NoPropertyFilter example mentioned above is typical.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my filter is not tracked by the service tracker, so by passing parameter 'true' to tracker.open() the filter was tracked:

```
this.tracker.open(true);
```