# How To Get Current Jackrabbit User In Felix Request Filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, jackrabbit, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I need to get current jackrabbit/session user when a request filter does filter.
I've implemented filter class as my past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310491/apache-felix-filter-issue)

Answer (score 1):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310491/apache-felix-filter-issue) I assume you are using Apache Sling - if you follow my advice there and use a [Sling-aware Filter](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html), you can cast the request to `SlingHttpServletRequest` in the filter's doFilter(...) method.

The `SlingHttpServletRequest's` `getResource()` method then provides the current `Resource`, which you can adapt to a JCR `Session` which then provides the Jackrabbit user.

Something like (without any checks for the example)

```
((SlingHttpServletRequest)request).getResource().getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class)...
```